# How to run Macro by selecting column A till the data exists

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba, win32com

I am trying to run a macro from `python` and `win32com.client`. My macro is working fine when i am trying manually, Because it has to run by selecting column A and rows till data exists.
Macro has Text column functionality and creating headings as well.

[image]

results
[image]

But when i try from code it is not working as expected.

```
import win32com.client as wincl

excel_app = wincl.DispatchEx("Excel.application")
excel_workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename=temp_macro_template_file_path, ReadOnly=1)
excel_app.Visible = True
excel_app.Columns('A')
excel_app.Application.Run("Macroname")
excel_workbook.Save()
excel_app.Application.Quit()
```

This is what i am getting after this.

[image]

Comment: It might help to provide the VBA you're using.

Comment: This might be one of the few times it's ok to use `.select`. Have you tried `excel_app.Columns('A').select`?

Comment: We can't help you fix your VBA without the VBA....